# How to share a text on Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am implementing on my app a button which lets me share a text on facebook, the text is captured in a TextView, the problem is that I don't really know how to do it, i need your help.

Hope you can help me :D

Comment: Have you tried installing the Android SDK for Facebook. That would be the first step. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: You can not share any text that you wrote. The user them self needs to have typed the text they want to share